# In Angular 13, can I get the Route ancestry in CanLoad guard?

Tags: angular, angular13

So I have a root app module and a tree of lazy-loaded modules. And each of them has a `CanLoad` guard. What I need is to get the `Route[]` from root to current (or reverse) `CanLoad(route: Route, ...)`.

So let's say module `A`, lazy-loads module `B`, which lazy-loads module `C`. I want to get an array of `Route` containing `A,B,C` or `C,B,A` so I can pull some data from them. Is this possible? Does Angular have the notion of the previously loaded (loader/parent) module in the `CanLoad` call?

*I'm really new to this... any hints are appreciated.*

- I've found some `.parent` properties but they seem to return null.
- `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()` gives me the final URL, even as it's loading parent modules getting to my child module as I press F5.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ActivatedRoute` service, whih contains observables related to the router state. https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

From the docs:

```js
export class ActivatedRouteComponent {
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const id: Observable<string> = route.params.pipe(map(p => p.id));
    const url: Observable<string> = route.url.pipe(map(segments => segments.join('')));
    // route.data includes both `data` and `resolve`
    const user = route.data.pipe(map(d => d.user));
  }
}
```

Call `route.snapshot` to get a snapshot instead of observables https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot.

From the docs

```js
class MyComponent {
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const id: string = route.snapshot.params.id;
    const url: string = route.snapshot.url.join('');
    const user = route.snapshot.data.user;
  }
}
```